# How to use variable inside parameter $_GET? example: ($_GET[$my_var])

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, parameters, get

I'm developing a plugin for wordpress, the parameter of the $ _GET is recorded in the database according to the preference of the User via the Wordpress Admin Panel. The following validation has to be via the $ _GET, this is the function:

```
$db_url = get_option('my_get_url');
// returns the value of the database entered by User
// on this case return -->  page=nosupport

$url_explode = explode("=", $db_url);
$url_before = $url_explode[0]; // --> page
$url_after = $url_explode[1]; // --> nosupport

echo "Before: ".$url_before; // here are ok, return --> page
echo "After: ".$url_after; // here are ok, return --> nosupport
```

My problem is here:

```
// here $_GET no have any value, dont work on validate...
if($_GET[$url_before] != ""){ 
    if($_GET['$url_before']=="nosupport"){
        // my function goes here...
    }
}
```

I using for test the parameter:

```
echo $_GET[$url_before];
```

But dont return any value...

Comment: `$_GET['$url_before'] != $_GET[$url_before]`, lose the quotes.

Comment: Aside from the quotes thing, he did say that the unquoted version still returned nothing

Comment: you might want to check what is in the whole `$_GET` array just in case `$url_before` is set incorrectly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, i had already tested all of these options, but ever dont working, the problem was that I was testing the function inside the main page of my site, and on the main page (mysite.com) does not get the parameter (?page=nossuport), so always returning null values​​, when I used the variable in the GET or used the echo $GET[$my_var] to test.. It was a great carelessness of mine, would never work...

by the way, the two parameters works correctly:

```
$_GET[$url_before]
$_GET["$url_before"]
```

The Problem are solved, Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_GET[$url_before] != ""){ 
    if($_GET[$url_before]=="nosupport"){ // note no "" here
        // my function goes here...
    }
}
```

In your solution, the key was treated as a string, with no variables evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to take out the ' in the second condition.

You wrote:

```
     $_GET['$url_before']
```

I'm guessing it should be:

```
     $_GET[$url_before]
```

Answer (score 0):

foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
 if($key == "nosupport"){

}
}